# What Causes No Such Element Exception

Tags: java, exception, crash, logic, conditional-statements

In my code I am getting a no such element exception when I enter a word. It does output the word correctly and the hangman, but it also crashses after doing so. What is causing this and how could I fix it? 
Here is the start of the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at Hangman.paint(Hangman.java:50)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
```

Also would it be hard to modify my code so that each time the computer guesses it draws one part of the hangman instead of it all appearing upon executing the program?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;

public class Hangman extends JApplet
{
    public void paint (Graphics Page)
    {
                //gallows
                Page.drawLine(0,300,20,300);
                Page.drawLine(10,40,10,300);
                Page.drawLine(10,40,80,40);
                Page.drawLine(80,40,80,55);

                //torso
                Page.drawOval(50,55,50,55);
                Page.drawOval(50,100,50,100);
                //left arm and hand
                Page.drawLine(50,150,40,110);
                Page.drawLine(40,110, 45,100);
                Page.drawLine(40,110, 25,100);
                Page.drawLine(40,110, 25,115);


                //right arm and hand
                Page.drawLine(100,150,120,110);
                Page.drawLine(120,110, 115,95);
                Page.drawLine(120,110, 125,95);
                Page.drawLine(120,110, 135,115);

                //left  leg and foot
                Page.drawLine(80,200,100,250);
                Page.drawLine(100,250, 115,260);


                //right leg and foot
                Page.drawLine(75,200,60,250);
                Page.drawLine(60,250,45,260);




     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter a 4 or 5 letter word and the computer will play hangman against you!");
     String word = in.nextLine();


     char[] letter = word.toCharArray();


     for (int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
             letter[i] = 'a';
     }


     for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
         for (int j = 48; j < 122; j++) {

                     if (letter[i] == word.charAt(i)) { 
                             break; 
                     } else {
                             letter[i] = (char)((int) j + 1);
                     }
             }
     }
     System.out.println("Your word is: ");

     for (char letters : letter) {
             System.out.print(letters);
     }
     in.close();
}

}
```

Comment: Could you please share the actual exception message? Usually it will have a line number that could provide clues

Comment: It's pretty long but here is the start of it:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
 at Hangman.paint(Hangman.java:50)
 at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1):

Do **not** close `in` inside your `paint` method.  It closes the underlying stream and the next attempt to read from it produces the error.

It's hardly ever a good idea to close `Scanner` object associated with  `System.in`.

From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html): "When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source implements the Closeable interface."

Comment: Oh really? Ok thanks! I've been closing everything since I started! Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: It runs now, but when I enter a word it does the output twice?

Enter a 4 or 5 letter word and the computer will play hangman against you!
hi
Your word is: 
hiEnter a 4 or 5 letter word and the computer will play hangman against you!

Comment: `paint` method is called multiple times. Put everything that needs to happen just at the beginning into `init()` method.  You need to learn some `Applet`/`JApplet` basics. You may want to start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html

Comment: Wait I'm confused. Where does the public void init() go? I tried putting it up top but then I was getting errors in relation to "}"

Comment: Have you worked through the tutorial that I provided a link for?

Comment: I did but I am still confused. My professor never showed us that before all semester and now we are at the end. I am a little lost still on how to implement it.

Comment: See if this helps: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/developingApplet.html

Answer (score 0):

Try checking to see if there is a next line before doing in.nextLine.

```
while(in.hasNextLine())
{
    word = in.nextline();
}
```

The problem is that you are calling nextLine() and it's throwing an exception when there's no line, try looking at the javadoc:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: You're wrong.  Since OP's reading from `stdin`, `hasNext` will always return `true`.